# How to make a PVP free zone

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What is the best way to make a PVP free zone, whether it be using commands or by using settings, for a Minecraft realm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Put them on a team

Scoreboard teams have a friendly fire option, which, when it is set to false, makes it impossible for players on the same team to hurt each other.

First set up the team itself

```
/scoreboard teams add noPvP
/scoreboard teams option noPvP friendlyfire false
```

Place two command blocks on a clock (or use repeat/chain command blocks from 1.9) and have them run

```
/scoreboard teams join noPvP @a[team=!noPvP,x=X,y=Y,z=Z,r=R1]
/scoreboard teams leave noPvP @a[team=noPvP,x=X,y=Y,z=Z,rm=R2]
```

Replace `X`, `Y`, `Z` with the coordinates in the center of your PvP-free zone. `R1` and `R2` are the radii of the zone. They are different since you don't want the literal edge-case where a player constantly joins and leaves the team. By making `R2` a few blocks larger than `R1`, the border is a bit more "fuzzy".

Note that players can't be on two teams at the same time, meaning that if you already have teams set up, things are a bit more complicated. You could, however, "remember" the originally assigned team by assigning a scoreboard tag corresponding to the team.

Comment: 1.13 syntax, `/team ...` instead of `/scorboard teams ...`. For add/remove commands, `/team join noPvP @a[team=!noPvP,x=X,y=Y,z=Z,distance=..R1]`, `/team join noPvP @a[team=!noPvP,x=X,y=Y,z=Z,distance=R2..]`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do this:
You simply have a clock (I used a hopper one) connected to a command block with this command `/effect @a[r=how far you want them to not be able to attack in the form of a number] weakness 1 255`  This will make them too weak to hit any entity including players while in the radius.

Comment: Last time I checked adventure mode doesn't prevent PVP. And the wiki doesn't say anything either...

Comment: Forgot, this will only make players not be able to break blocks.  Massive edit.

Answer (score -2):

maybe resistance? so you cant kill anyone ? command /effect @p resistance 9999 255 true